# Doctrine command line ignores input

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using doctrine in a wordpress-plugin. However, the command line tool does not work correctly. 
It seems to ignore all input or parameters, and just keeps displaying the default help text, no matter what I enter.

The PHP-Version is 7.0.7.

The content of my cli-config ( which sits in vendor/orm/bin/config ) looks like this:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../../../doctrine-bootstrap.php';

$spmm = new doctrineBootstrap();

$entityManager = $spmm->getEntityManager();

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);

?>
```

The content of the bootstrapper itself:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class doctrineBootstrap {

    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->initDoctrine();
    }

    private function initDoctrine() {
        $paths = array("/model");
        $isDevMode = false;

        // the connection configuration
        $dbParams = array(
            'host' => 'XXXX',
            'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
            'user'     => 'XXXX',
            'password' => 'XXXX',
            'dbname'   => 'XXXX',
        );

        $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
        $this->entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
    }

    public function getEntityManager() {
        return $this->entityManager;
    }
}
```

The command itself is not outputting any errors to the console, but in the php errorlog this error appears:

```
[26-Aug-2016 11:17:26 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: argv in /html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-openimmo/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 55
[26-Aug-2016 11:17:26 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-openimmo/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 59
[26-Aug-2016 11:17:26 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-openimmo/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 276
[26-Aug-2016 11:17:26 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-openimmo/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 276
[26-Aug-2016 11:17:26 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-openimmo/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php on line 276
```

I'm a little confused because the documentation on this isn't very clear about this. How do I get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out what was causing my problem:

In the end, its was a path problem with `getcwd()` and `php_cli` vs `php` and disabled error output via php.ini.

As I mentioned in my question, my cli-config lies in `vendor/orm/bin/config`, which is correct if you want to run you command with `php`.

If you run the command with `php_cli`, it wants the config file in the current directory that the command is executed in. When I first tried with php_cli, I simple got no response at all. So I tried `php_cli -n` with the command and got the error about missing `cli-config.php`. So I copied the file, and voila, its working. I simply didnt see the error message because error output was disabled by default.

However, if you want to run it with php, make sure the `register_argc_argv` directive is set to ON in your php.ini.